# How does one create a polarized beam of particles?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, polarization, accelerator-physics, particle-accelerators

I want to know how experimental physicists create spin-polarised beams of particles, say electrons, muons or quarks. My first guess is that one would polarise such a beam in a magnetic field. The two spin-states will have slightly different energies and the particles will spontaneously decay into the lower energy spin state. However, I see two problems with that. The energy gap should be minuscule and the lifetime of the higher energy state therefore quite high, such that unstable particles might decay first. Also, the magnetic field will cause charged particles to be deviated by the Lorenz force.

Comment: An apparatus like the one used in the famous Stern Gerlach experiment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Gerlach_experiment 

The idea is that a gradient in the magnetic field will exert a force on particles, with its direction depending on their spin.

Comment: So you Filter the unwanted polarisation out and then recollimate the beam?

Comment: exactly, but I'm not saying this from my own experience, so maybe this technique is considered obsolete (I really do not know). That's why I only commented with an option I saw in some schemes, and not a full answer. I suggest you wait to more answers :)

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable in the details of their operation, but at RHIC the polarization is done by devices called Siberian Snakes. The polarization achieved is on order of 50%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While synchrotron radiation have an effect of self-polarization (and is actually the only way to polarize a positron beam) often, when a highly polarized beam is required, it is produced straight from the source and kept such to the best extent through all the accelerator chain.

For ring-shaped machines special sections are introduced which rotate the spin in such a way that the bending magnets do not affect it any further. These sections often include solenoid magnets and/or a combination of horizontal and vertical bends, therefore they are friendly called Snakes. The first family of them was invented in Novosibirsk, and got the adjective Siberian.

These can be avoided entirely by going for a figure-8 design such as the JLab EIC. In this case, the effect of dipoles cancel out and the spin is automatically and effectively realigned after a full turn.

These are of course the cases in which you want high beam current/energy and/or you are operating a collider. If you can afford to waste a significant fraction of the beam and have a fixed target experiment, then you can do any kind of filtering.